# C++ Infinite Loop causing a stack overflow error?

Tags: c++, function, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

Okay, so I've been working on my calculator. I am currently trying to get it to tell the difference between a valid integer and a character. As an easy workaround I did:

```
int calc()
{
cout << "Number 1:"; cin >> fnum;
cout << "Number 2:"; cin >> snum;
    if (snum <= -1000 || fnum <= -1000)
    {
        cout << ("Error: Invalid Number!") << endl;
        calc();
    }
    else
    {
        ff();
    }
return 0;
}
```

And whenever I enter in a character it goes into an infinite loop saying:
SymbolHere:Number 1:Number 2:

ff(); is calling in the calculation function.

I was wondering how to fix this and prevent a stack overflow/ infinite loop? Pastebin Link: http://pastebin.com/GxN2uJAQ

Comment: Check the result of the input operation.

Comment: What added value does recusion add in this case as opposed to just a while loop?

Comment: That is **not** an infinite loop, but rather infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ok, there are a number of things with this code.

```
wait = 0;
while (wait <= 5)
{
   wait++;
}
```

will do absolutely nothing, your program will increment so fast this is undetectable to the human mind. I would recommend removing this entirely.

```
if (snum >= 0 || fnum >= 0)
                {
    cout << ("Error: Invalid Number!") << endl;
    wait = 0;
    while (wait <= 5)
    {
       wait++;
    }
    system("CLS");
    calc();
    }
```

why are you sending an error message if these numbers are valid? Unless you are only adding negative numbers, this should have a different range.

your function calls also never resolve back into main, instead they call each other (`ff` and `calc`) infinity, the program honestly has too many flaws and bad programming practices. Drop whichever tutorial/book you have and try finding a more up to date list(sorry for being harsh, but it has to be said).

[C++ Primer Plus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321776402)

[CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/)

[TheNewBoston](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=16&number=1)(Recommended)

---

You probably have an input fail by entering say a char for an int, you need to make sure to catch anything thrown by cin and clear the state:

```
std::string err = "error!";
try {
    std::cin >> x;
    if(!cin)
        throw err;
    //....
}
catch(std::string& ee)
{
    std::cout << ee << std::endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
```

make sure to include `<limits>` in your file.

Comment: The whole point of that part of the code was to check if it was a number or not. Because let's say... LOL is neither >= -1000 because it is not a number so it should fail the test. So it does. But when it goes back it continues the loop without even asking the user's input. I attempted to counter this by setting both variables to zero before an input was requested. But it still went into a loop. (I am also very new to C++ hence why I made a simple calculator) If you need to see all of the code you can find it here: http://pastebin.com/GxN2uJAQ

Comment: You need to post your loop then, not just it's function.

Comment: @user2396111 I added an edit in. It's not pretty, but hopefully you'll take my advice.

Comment: The wait function was an experiment. Most of what I learned I am teaching myself. I read a few chapters of a book and decided to give it a shot.

Comment: Okay, so I had a friend go over it and he cleared ALOT of things up. Just by moving things to different places and ending the main(); function early!